# Getting back to MENU from LOOP

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop

I have a problem with simple program for rolling RPG dices
It has function to chose whitch type of dice you want to roll and while you press enter, it rolls chosen dice.

The thing is, i want to add function, that allows user to press "b" to return to main menu and i am stuck with this one.
Code looks like this:

```
import random, sys

#Kości: k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7, k8, k10
#k12, k14, k16, k24, k30, k48, k50, k100, k1000



def rzut(kosc):
    while True:

            if kosc == '1':
                print('Rzut kością k3 \nNaciśnij ENTER, aby rzucić \nNaciśnij b, aby wrócić do menu\n\n')
                k2 = input()
                if k2 == '':
                    print(str(random.randint(1, 2)).center(10,''))
                    print('\n\n')
                if k2 == 'b':
                        break

            if kosc == '2':
                print('Rzut kością k3 \nNaciśnij ENTER, aby rzucić \nNaciśnij b, aby wrócić do menu\n\n')
                k3 = input()
                if k3 == '':
                    print(str(random.randint(1, 3)).center(10,''))
                    print('\n\n')
                if k3 == 'b':
                    break


while True:
    print('KościRPG'.center(23, '*'))
    print('MENU'.center(23, '='))
    print('Wybierz kość'.center(23))
    print('Naciśnij "q", aby wyjść'.center(23))
    print(' 1: k2 --- 9: k12'.center(23, ' '))
    print(' 2: k3 --- 10: k14'.center(23, ' '))
    print(' 3: k4 --- 11: k16'.center(23, ' '))
    print(' 4: k5 --- 12: k24'.center(23, ' '))
    print(' 5: k6 --- 13: k30'.center(23, ' '))
    print(' 6: k7 --- 14: k48'.center(23, ' '))
    print(' 7: k8 --- 15: k50'.center(23, ' '))
    print('8: k10 --- 16: k100'.center(26, ' '))
    print(' 17: k1000'.center(20, ' '))

    kosc = rzut(str(input()))
    if kosc == rzut('q'):
        sys.exit()
```

I know, that there are multiple programs like that and written even better, but this is just my attempt to learn material from book. Just a noobie-Python question because i bang my head on the wall with this one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no one seems to even try to help me here, so i help myself.
I just made function title() and replace "break" with:

```
if k2 == 'b':
    title()
```